# Minimum number of moves to make all elements of the sequence zero.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given $N$ numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ I want to make $a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n = 0$ by using minimum number of operations. An operation is taking any two numbers $a_i$ and $a_j$ ($i$ may be equal to $j$) and calculating $a_i$ xor $a_j$ and replacing $a_i$ with it and replacing $a_j$ with it. How to calculate minimum number of operations required to make all numbers in the sequecne $0$? XOR is defined to be bitwise xor.

Comment: That depends on the numbers $a_i$. Of course there is the obvious way of doing $a_i XOR a_i$, giving us $n$ operations, but depending on what the $a_i$ actually are, you might be able to do it in $n/2$; or even less if some of the $a_i$ are already zero to begin with. Thus, you might want to redefine what you are looking for, because depending on the given numbers, the minimal number of steps might be different.

Comment: $a_i$ are any nonnegative integers (not necessarily different). You may assume that they fit in 32 bit variables.

Comment: Then $a_i XOR a_i$. If you have no other information on them and also don't want your algorithm to check for such information, this should be the minimal number of operations that work for any such numbers.

Comment: It is not minimal. Consider sequence $1$, $1$, $2$. Your strategy does it in $3$ moves while you can do $1$ xor $1$ and then the sequence is $0$, $0$, $2$ and then $2$ xor $2$ and it is $0$, $0$, $0$. $2$ moves was enough.

Comment: With standard assumptions on complexity, it will take you more time to look for an optimal number of operations, than just doing the $n$ operations Dirk Liebhold pointed out. If you really don't care about the time spent to look for an optimal sequence, I suggest stating it explicitly to avoid confusion (for people with that particular background).

Comment: I've asked for the minimum number of moves, not what would be more optimal...

Comment: You did, but I think people whose background is more related to algorithms complexity rather than combinatorics could misinterpret "fastest way". This is only a suggestion so don't mind it.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim** : There is a sequence of minimal length where every XOR operation is done between two equal numbers.

*Proof* :
Consider a sequence of operation with minimal length, and let $(i,j)$ be the last operation between two distinct numbers $x_i\neq x_j$. After this operation, registers $r_i$ and $r_j$ will contain number $x_i\oplus x_j$.
Because $x_i\neq x_j$ necessarily $x_i\oplus x_j\neq 0$, so there exist one or two more operations $(i,k)$ and $(j,l)$ after $(i,j)$. There are three cases depending on whether $l,k\in\{i,j\}$.

- Both $l,k\in\{i,j\}$, there is only one more operation which is again $(i,j)$. Instead of doing $(i,j)$ twice, we can do $(i,i)$ and $(j,j)$.
- $k\notin\{i,j\}$ and $l\in\{i,j\}$. We necessarily have $l=j$. Registers $r_i,r_j,r_k$ are set to zero by the three operations $(i,j)$, $(i,k)$ and $(j,j)$. Those can be replaced by $(i,i)$, $(j,j)$ and $(k,k)$.
- Both $l,k\notin\{i,j\}$. Because $(i,l)$ and $(j,k)$ must set all four registers $r_i,r_j,r_k,r_l$ to zero, we deduce that registers $r_k$ and $r_l$ must contain number $x_i\oplus x_j$. It follows that we can also set those four registers to zero with the series of operations $(i,i)$, $(j,j)$ and $(k,l)$.

It follows that we can remove every operation between distinct numbers, and that there exists a sequence of minimum length with only operations between equal numbers.

---

Suppose you have $k$ distinct numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ with multiplicity $m_1,\ldots,m_k$, $\sum_{i=1}^k m_i=n$. Then the length of the minimal sequence is $$\text{opt}=\sum_{i=1}^k\left\lceil \frac{m_i}2 \right\rceil$$